# Java File behaves strange

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I am really confused about java strange behavior.

My code is;

```
public class Main {
    private static String KK_PATH = "C:\\Users\\ahopyar\\Desktop\\kk.txt";
    private static String EXCELL_PATH = "‪C:\\Users\\ahopyar\\Desktop\\kk.txt";
    static List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        readExcell();
    }

    private static void readExcell() throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        File file = new File(KK_PATH);
        System.out.println(file.exists());
    }
}
```

if I run this code it prints "true" but if I change `File file = new File(KK_PATH);` as `File file = new File(EXCELL_PATH);` it prints false.

How this can be possible and how can I fix it? (There is file at "C:\Users\ahopyar\Desktop\kk.txt")

Comment: There is an invisible "[LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm)" character at the start of your `EXCELL_PATH`.

Comment: Copied the code given and created the file, seems to work.

Comment: Syntax sugar note you may use `c:/some/folder/file.txt` a single forward slash even in Windows platform, I find it less error prone and easier to read unlike escaped double-backslash.

Comment: @Ivar I'm just curious how you even found this hehe?

Comment: When strings like these appear to be completely equal, I usually start selecting a bit before it and Shift + right arrow through the string to see if it hangs on a specific spot. That's a sign of some kind of invisible character. :)

Comment: @Ivar what can I do to solve the problem? I just copied the content not wrote them seperatly?

Comment: Rewrite the string by deleting the entire string and then type it in by hand to make sure you don't copy paste the same mistake again

Comment: this was really strange :). Thaks for your help Ivar and Neijwiert